# Issue with XSD schema in transforming data from XML to JSON format

Tags: java, json, xml, xsd

I am trying to transform data from xml to json format, For that I have written xsd schema from the xml output to transform data from xml to json.

Following is my xml which needs to be transformed to json

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <SyncData>
   <Employerid>12345</Employerid>
   <ImporterEmail>abcdef@xyz.com</ImporterEmail>
   <ReportEmail>abcdefggggg@xyz.com</ReportEmail>
   <Employees>
   <wd:WorkerSummary xmlns:is="java:com.workday.esb.intsys.xpath.
    ParsedIntegrationSystemFunctions" 
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
   xmlns:xdiff="urn:com.workday/esb/xdiff" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
   <wd:ReferenceID/>
   <wd:Name>abcdef,ghijklm</wd:Name>
   <wd:Title/>
   <wd:EmployeeId>JG00889</wd:EmployeeId>
   <wd:EMail>sderf.rtyui@xyzz.com</wd:EMail>                                                        
   <wd:AddressLine1>1400 Post Alm Tyui</wd:AddressLine1>                           
  <wd:City>Bostonn</wd:City>                                                                                 
  <wd:State>MC</wd:State>                                                                                      
  <wd:Zip>11067</wd:Zip>                                                                               
  <wd:Country>AUS</wd:Country>                                                                              
  </wd:WorkerSummary>                                                                                                                     
  </Employees>                                                                                                                               
  </SyncData>
```

Following are the two different xsd schema’s that I have defined from the above stated xml and I am getting different error’s for each one.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                                                        
  <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  targetNamespace="http://www.your-company.com/WorkermapSchema" 
  xmlns:tns="http://www.your-company.com/WorkermapSchema" 
  elementFormDefault="qualified">                                                                       
  <xs:element name="WorkerSummary">                                               
  <xs:complexType>                                                                                      
  <xs:sequence>                                                                                                     
  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="ReferenceID" />                                     
  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Name" />                                                    
  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Title" />                                                     
  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="EmployeeId" />                                          
  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="EMail" />                                                 
  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="AddressLine1" />                                          
  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="City" />                                                    
  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="State" />                                                    
  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Zip" />                                                        
  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Country" />                                          
  </xs:sequence>                                                                                      
  </xs:complexType>                                                                                           
  </xs:element>                                                                                                        
  </xs:schema>
```

The error I was getting with this schema is as following

> com.workday.esb.xmltojson.XmlToJsonException: Root Element type not found "SyncData"

Since the above error says the Root Element “SyncData” not found, I have tried to define schema in other way with the Root Element as following.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" 
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-
   microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:app1="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
   <xs:import namespace="urn:com.workday/bsvc"></xs:import>
   <xs:element name="SyncData">
   <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Employerid" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="ImporterEmail" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="ReportEmail" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="Employees" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="WorkerSummary" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="ReferenceID" type="xs:string"/>             
        </xs:sequence>
       </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" 
  msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
  <xs:complexType>
  <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element ref="SyncData" />
   </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

After using the above xsd schema, I am not getting error related to Root Element “SyncData”, But I am getting a different error which I am not understanding what it is about, The error is as following.

> org.codehaus.stax2.typed.TypedXMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[2,359] Message: Element content can not contain child START_ELEMENT when using Typed Access methods

Is there anything wrong in the schema or what is the error is about?

I have tried multiple attempts on xsd schema to execute it perfectly as required, but seems something is missing which I am not sure that is causing the failure.

Comment: You are missing one in each schema. While you got WorkerSummary correct in 1st schema, you got it wrong and made it to simple element and not object in second schema. `<xs:element name="WorkerSummary" type="xs:string"/>` which means it can not contain child element.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response, I tried to mention Element "SyncData"  in my 1st schema but i couldn't do that as it was not allowed to do so.And i tried to add element WorkerSummary in my second schema,But i am seeing error as The element type "xs:element" must be terminated by the matching end tag "</xs:element>".

Comment: Basically you have to include two schema. let me post that as answer.

Comment: Asking someone to provide you things is not what you should be asking in SO, this is for programming **questions**. Also `required needful ` doesn't really mean anything, maybe only in India?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="SyncData">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Employerid" type="xsd:int" />
        <xsd:element name="ImporterEmail" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="ReportEmail" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="Employees">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="wd:WorkerSummary">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="wd:ReferenceID" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element name="wd:Name" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element name="wd:Title" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element name="wd:EmployeeId" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element name="wd:EMail" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element name="wd:AddressLine1" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element name="wd:City" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element name="wd:State" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element name="wd:Zip" type="xsd:int" />
                    <xsd:element name="wd:Country" type="xsd:string" />
                  </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Seems it is executing after removing wd: from all element names.Also i see error  java.lang.NumberFormatException. But i see for Elements Employerid and Zip,element type is given as integer.Not sure which element is causing this, Please suggest.